# Is it possible to have CSP only apply to the parent frame, not any iframes?

Tags: html, iframe, sandbox, content-security-policy

If I have a webpage with CSP set to:

```
default-src 'self'; img-src *
```

Or similar, and I have an iframe like such:

```
some legal content
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" srcdoc="&lt;script>alert('arbitrary code')&lt;/script>"></iframe>
```

Is it possible to allow the code in the iframe to disobey the parent frame's CSP and allow inline scripts/styles, content from other domains, or any other arbitrary HTML thing that doesn't violate the sandbox restrictions?

Currently this will give:

> [Error] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. (about:srcdoc, line 1)

The [CSP spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#processing-model-iframe-srcdoc) confirms this is correct behavior:

> Whenever a user agent creates [an `iframe`
>       `srcdoc` document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#an-iframe-srcdoc-document) in a browsing context nested in the
>       protected resource, if the user agent is [enforcing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#enforce) any [policies](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#security-policy)
>       for the protected resource, the user agent MUST [enforce](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#enforce) those
>       [policies](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#security-policy) on the `iframe` `srcdoc` document as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible.

The are only two ways to accomplish what you're after:

1. Alter the CSP rules of the parent page to whitelist your arbitrary code (I would suggest using a CSP nonce or hash for your arbitrary content rather than unsafe-inline).
2. Point your iframe to an external (sub)domain with rules you can control and whitelist it with `frame-src` & `child-src` (see point 1).

Comment: So basically I need to set up an echo server which just spits back arbitrary code so the iframe isn't an "iframe srcdoc document"?

Comment: Yes, but that echo server has to be on the same domain, port & protocol as the original document (because that is `'self'`). Or you need to add a `frame-src https://domain.com/; child-src https://domain.com/` to the parent document because `frame-src` and `child-src` (used for iframes in older and newer browsers respectively) inherit from `default-src` if they aren't set explicitly.

Comment: This is still a problem in 2023 :( I have also tried using `<iframe src="data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,<script>alert(1)</script>"></iframe>` but that didn't work either.